# Can we use Reflection to read COM object properties info?

Tags: c#, reflection, com, rcw

Can we use Reflection to read COM object properties info?

I am trying to get Property Name and Value of a COM object using the below code.

But it fails.

here **connection** is my COM object.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo info in connection.GetType().GetProperties())
        {

        MyProperty property = new MyProperty();
        property.Name = info.Name;
        property.Value = info.GetValue(connection, null);
    }
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Sure, if connection is an RCW that came from a type in an interop library that was created by tlbimp.exe.  Apparently it wasn't.  Easy to see in the debugger, if it just shows a __ComObject with no properties then you're done.

Comment: Yes Hans it shows as __ComObject in debugger.

Comment: So how to use Reflection now??? above code is not working.

Comment: Do you know the type of the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Reflection, but you can use `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor` :

```
PropertyDescriptor[] properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(connection)
  .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray();
PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = properties
  .Single(p => p.DisplayName == "NameOfProperty");
object propertyValue = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(connection);
```